# c++ templates sintaxis

Tags: c++

¿Cómo defino un metodo friend en este template con parámetro exta?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

template <typename T>
class Myclass{
private:
    T m_a;
    public:
    getm(){ return m_a;};
    MyClass(T a)m_a(a){ return; };
    template <typename D>
    friend  MyClass<D> convert(MyClass<T> param);//esto compila hasta 
    //aqui
}

//esto no compila
template<typename T>
template<typename D>
MyClass<D> convert(MyClass<T> param){
    //aqui se hace lo que proceda pues al ser friend
    //tengo pleno acceso a la clase
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Tu código, salvo que te haya fallado la operación de copypaste, no va a compilar en la vida porque tiene varios errores:

```
template <typename T>
class Myclass{ // 1
private:
    T m_a;
    public:
    getm(){ return m_a;}; // 2
    MyClass(T a)m_a(a){ return; }; // 3

    template <typename D>
    friend  MyClass<D> convert(MyClass<T> param);
} // 4
```

Que te enumero a continuación:

1. Es `MyClass`, no `Myclass` (nota la `c` minúscula). C++ es sensible al uso de mayúsculas, no lo olvides
2. Falta indicar el tipo de retorno en `getm`
3. La inicialización de los miembros se hace después de poner dos puntos `:`
4. La declaración de clases debe terminar siempre por punto y coma.

Y a modo de bonus:

- La implementación de las funciones no es necesario finalizarlas con punto y coma.
- Si una función no hace nada se dejan las dos llaves vacías y listo.

Tu clase debería quedar más bien así:

```
template <typename T>
class MyClass{
private:
    T m_a;

public:
    T getm(){ return m_a;}
    MyClass(T a): m_a(a){ }

    template <typename D>
    friend  MyClass<D> convert(MyClass<T> param);//esto compila hasta 
    //aqui
};
```

Para futuras consultas no mientas porque pierdes tu credibilidad. No digas que tu código compila cuando no es así.

Tratando ahora tu problema con la función `friend`, la función va a usar dos tipos distintos, luego una posible solución sería declarar ambos explícitamente:

```
template <typename T>
class MyClass{
private:
    // ...    
    template<typename A, typename B>
    friend MyClass<A> convert(MyClass<B>);
};
```

Aunque teniendo en cuenta que en el código que muestras no hay necesidad de que la función sea `friend`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

template <typename T>
class MyClass{
private:
    T m_a;

public:
    T getm(){ return m_a;}
    MyClass(T a): m_a(a){ }
};

template<typename D, typename T>
MyClass<D> convert(MyClass<T> param){
    return MyClass<D>(static_cast<D>(param.getm()));
}

int main()
{
    MyClass<int> a(10);
    MyClass<short> b = convert<short>(a);
    std::cout << b.getm() << '\n';
}
```

Comment: si pero el html es la unica forma que conozco para formatear el texto en este sitio de forma apropiada :me hice un lio cuando lo intente por primera vez sin html

Comment: @FJsanto Para escribir en SO no hace falta usar HTML

Comment: gracias por la respuesta, yo tenia un problema similar y ahora noto que no se utiliza la palabra friend a la hora de implementar la funcion